# Unable to read filenames in a for loop and print the arrays

Tags: python, arrays, csv, glob

I am trying to loop through a folder of 70 csv files. Each file has 2 columns and I want to store them in 2 different arrays. I am not able to print the file names in the folder and my arrays are not being appended. I want the output to produce the file name with its a respective arrays.

```
path=r"E:\Users\ConfocalUser\Documents\GitHub\qudi"
files=glob.glob(os.path.join(path,'*.csv')

xData=[]
yData=[]
for file in files:
    print(file)
    with open(path,"r") as f_in:
        reader=csv.reader(f_in)
        next(reader)
        for line in reader:
            try:
                float_1,float_2=float(line[0]),float(line[1])
                xData.append(float_1)
                yData.append(float_2)
            except ValueError:
                continue
```

Comment: Replace ```path``` with ```file``` and check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you do

```
    with open(path,"r") as f_in:
        reader=csv.reader(f_in)
        next(reader)
```

instead of

```
    with open(file,"r") as f_in:
        reader=csv.reader(f_in)
```

`reader()` expects a csv file, not a list of pathnames.

Comment: i am still unable to print the files and arrays

Comment: Unable to get any output file names when do, from glob import glob
# change the current working directory
os.chdir(r"E:\Users\ConfocalUser\Documents\GitHub\qudi")
print(os.getcwd())
for filename in glob("/*csv"):
    print(filename)

Comment: @AngelaMary Use ```os``` module to change directories and get the files rather than ```glob```

Comment: The first two lines in your OP are correct, and will return a list of filenames in `files`